# An inequality involving distances

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, metric-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ a smooth bounded domain and $u \in C^1(\Omega)$ a nonnegative function. Supose that both sets
$$
\Omega_0 := \{x \in \Omega : u(x) = 0\}
$$
and
$$
\Omega_{+} := \{u \in \Omega : u(x) > 0\}
$$
are nonempty. Show that there axists and $y \in \Omega_{+}$ such that
$$
d(y, \Omega_0) < d(y, \partial \Omega).
$$

I have tried using that, given $x \in \partial \Omega_0$, taking a ball centered in $x$  with radius $\epsilon$, it has do interset $\Omega_+$. As $\Omega_0$ is closed, $x \in \Omega_0$. I guess $\partial\Omega_0 \cap \partial \Omega = \emptyset$, but I'm not sure. Assuming this, I tried to take $\epsilon < d(\partial \Omega_0, \partial \Omega)$, but I didn't succed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement as given is not actually true unless $\Omega$ is a connected domain. (Because otherwise, $\Omega$ could consists of two parts, one on which $u=0$ and one on which $u=1$, and the statement would not be true.)

So let's assume that the domain is connected. We know that on part of the domain, the function is zero and on some other part it is positive. Because the function is continuous, there must be at least one point where the two parts of the domain touch, i.e., $S=\overline{\Omega_0} \cap \overline{\Omega_+}$ is non-empty. That's basically your construction, just avoiding looking at the boundary of the domains to avoid having to think whether $\Omega_0,\Omega_+$ are open or closed (which isn't so easy to decide because $\Omega$ itself, being a domain, is open.

Now you need to think whether $S$ could be part of the boundary of $\Omega$. It can't, because the domain itself is open. So $S$ must be a non-empty subset of the interior of $\Omega$. That means that you can find a point $x_0\in S$ that has a positive distance $\delta$ from $\partial\Omega$. And because $x_0\in S$, you can draw a ball of radius $\epsilon<\delta/4$ around $x_0$ so that that ball is completely contained in $\Omega$, and so that that ball overlaps $\Omega_+$. Pick any point $y$ in that ball. It has distance at most $\epsilon=\delta/4$ from $x_0$, which itself has distance $\delta$ from $\partial\Omega$. As a consequence you have
$$
  d(y,\partial\Omega_0)\le d(y,S)<d(y,x_0)<\epsilon<\delta/4
$$
and if you call the closest point on $\partial\Omega$ to $y$ by $a\in\partial\Omega$, you also have
$$
  d(y,a) \ge |d(y,x_0) - d(x_0,a)| = 3\delta/4.
$$
The result follows with a bit of arithmetic.